# Why I can't use C++ to create a heap bigger than 8GiB on Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, memory, heap-memory, clion

I use CLion to build this code on Windows 11. My system is 64bit and has 32GiB memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    int len = 0;
    std::cin >> len;
    auto arg = std::make_unique<int32_t[]>(len);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));
}
```

I'm trying to create a large dynamic array. When type of this array is `int` (4 BYTES), the maximum size of this array is around 8192MiB. If I change type of this array to `int16_t` (2 BYTES), the maximum size of this array is around 4096MiB. If I change type of this array to `char` (1 BYTES), the maximum size of this array is around 2048MiB.

```
| Size of variables | Max Memory (MiB) |
| ----------------- | ---------------- |
|      4 BYTES      |       8192       |
|      2 BYTES      |       4096       |
|      1 BYTES      |       2048       |
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgTF9.png)

[VMMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Fmf.png)

[TaskManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVrz8.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical maximum value that `int` can hold is 2,147,483,647 and it looks like your maximum size is limited by this limit of `int`.

Try using `long long` instead of `int` for `len`.